# Load image in WebView from application resources

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to load an image from application resources (`/res` directory)?

PD: I know I can load from assets but for commodity and to avoid duplication of images I want to load some from resources if it's possible.

Comment: What sort of duplication do you fear

Answer (score 0):

Worked in android 2.2

```
<img src = "file:///android_res/drawable/test.png" />
```

where tes.png is in the res/drawable-mdpi folder

Or Use this.

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"
```

Comment: And do you know if it's capable to select correct dpi version?